# How can i fix this type of problems in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am getting the following error after creating new project

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.+
Install Repository and sync project 
Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

I found some information about this problem. After that I searched for updates of the Android support repository and Google repository. I found an update for the  Google repository and updated it. Now my all SDK and studio is updated.

How do I deal with this error now?

Comment: Install new version of support repository and your problem will be gone.

Comment: But their is no update

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: i am sorry for let. my laptop is on service center and i get it to day dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}

Answer (score 0):

public class test1 extends AppCompatActivity {
private int conte = 100;

```
private  String b;
```

String i="CONFIRM";
    EditText vared;

```
int level=1;
 private  TextView end,leevel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(test1.this,"زما شما به اتمام رسید !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            Intent i = new Intent(test1.this, test2.class);
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
    },100000);


    end=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (conte>=0){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        end.setText(conte+"");
                        conte--;
                    }
                });
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    leevel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    vared=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vared) ;

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String b = vared.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(test1.this,"ذخیره شد حالا میتونی امتحان کنی !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });


    if( i==b) {
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                level++;
                leevel.setText(level + "");


            }
        });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(test1.this,"اسم وارد شده صخیخ نمیباشد !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please explain why your code answers the question. And please format the code properly, it is very difficult to read this way.